# Why does the «Variable Length Differ» Error Appear

Tags: r

I'm currently stuck on a very basic problem I think, but after searching on different blogs, I still haven't found an answer that can solve my case.

So, my goal at first was to find the best predictors with the leaps package using regsubset. You can find out how it works here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/selecting-the-best-predictors-for-linear-regression-in-r-f385bf3d93e9

Unfortunately, when I tried on my side, I got an Error:

```
Best_Subset = regsubsets(Val.Pred~., data = FinalData, nbest = 1, nvmax = NULL, force.in = NULL, force.out = NULL, method = "exhaustive")
Error in model.frame.default(data = FinalData, formula = Val.Pred ~ .) : 
  les longueurs des variables diffèrent (trouvé pour 'Total.output')
```

When I look at my data, I have the same number of observations for each variable, so I don't know what it refers to. I also don't have a "na" in my data. Here is my data frame:

```
> FinalData
   Total.output X40hp_US   Inflation Area_Small Imp_Cons_Small Sup_Rep_Small Tractor_Prop_Small  Area_Med Imp_Cons_Med Sup_Rep_Med Tractor_Prop_Med Area_Large Imp_Cons_Large Sup_Rep_Large Tractor_Prop_Large
1     0.8724991    91004  0.02826171  599050000       4.20e+09      6.19e+09          3.390e+09 202361025     1.73e+09    3.21e+09        2.080e+09  140658975       1.87e+09      3.30e+09          7.300e+08
2     0.8546510    96757  0.01586032  594085000       3.76e+09      5.37e+09          3.360e+09 203330341     2.18e+09    3.80e+09        2.080e+09  142884659       2.06e+09      3.03e+09          7.600e+08
3     0.8730354   125333  0.02270095  588678000       7.36e+09      5.01e+09          3.830e+09 203498740     2.39e+09    3.18e+09        2.110e+09  144573260       2.05e+09      2.81e+09          1.060e+09
4     0.9133158   133775  0.02677237  577418000       7.71e+09      5.26e+09          4.660e+09 206514906     2.61e+09    3.16e+09        2.560e+09  148327094       2.28e+09      3.18e+09          1.480e+09
5     0.9011035   127240  0.03392747  565186000       7.63e+09      5.43e+09          4.150e+09 210155008     2.52e+09    3.42e+09        2.720e+09  152598992       2.55e+09      3.75e+09          1.630e+09
6     0.8912164   122340  0.03225944  552126000       7.03e+09      5.48e+09          3.610e+09 215480174     2.70e+09    3.72e+09        2.120e+09  158183826       2.97e+09      4.20e+09          1.570e+09
7     0.9157829   113420  0.02852673  489497000       6.69e+09      5.25e+09          3.570e+09 247946789     3.39e+09    4.49e+09        2.860e+09  184016211       4.02e+09      5.36e+09          2.170e+09
8     0.9482022    98326  0.03839100  478050000       7.37e+09      5.29e+09          4.320e+09 251698346     4.00e+09    4.69e+09        4.260e+09  188851654       4.43e+09      5.92e+09          2.820e+09
9     0.9567983    78995 -0.00355546  468200000       7.39e+09      5.34e+09          3.510e+09 255546002     3.33e+09    4.78e+09        3.470e+09  193843998       3.38e+09      5.38e+09          2.320e+09
10    0.9443128    83227  0.01640043  454930000       5.89e+09      5.47e+09          4.010e+09 260759419     3.19e+09    5.04e+09        4.130e+09  199970581       3.52e+09      5.39e+09          2.760e+09
11    0.9463026    84561  0.03156842  440370000       5.88e+09      5.23e+09          8.360e+09 267025518     4.04e+09    5.36e+09        9.320e+09  207024482       4.38e+09      5.71e+09          7.320e+09
12    0.9454762    92196  0.02069337  422590000       6.52e+09      5.36e+09          1.022e+10 275819462     3.30e+09    4.51e+09        1.038e+10  216190538       5.78e+09      8.33e+09          1.340e+10
13    1.0140503   100589  0.01464833  419020000       6.55e+09      5.46e+09          1.048e+10 274880000     3.52e+09    4.62e+09        1.030e+10  217820000       6.53e+09      8.62e+09          1.342e+10
14    0.9938921   109612  0.01622223  412520000       6.68e+09      5.26e+09          1.166e+10 275130000     3.97e+09    4.86e+09        9.120e+09  221270000       7.55e+09      9.78e+09          1.302e+10
15    1.0000000   118237  0.00118627  408340000       6.50e+09      5.38e+09          1.034e+10 273370000     3.45e+09    5.12e+09        6.460e+09  224080000       6.15e+09      8.20e+09          7.000e+09
16    1.0264209   132819  0.01261583  406360000       6.03e+09      4.88e+09          8.840e+09 271560000     3.20e+09    5.02e+09        6.060e+09  224760000       5.27e+09      7.70e+09          6.300e+09
17    1.0299837   143574  0.02130110  404130000       6.69e+09      5.39e+09          9.880e+09 268560000     3.16e+09    4.70e+09        7.000e+09  227680000       6.35e+09      7.91e+09          8.120e+09

str(FinalData)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Total.output      : num  0.872 0.855 0.873 0.913 0.901 ...
 $ X40hp_US          : num  91004 96757 125333 133775 127240 ...
 $ Inflation         : num  0.0283 0.0159 0.0227 0.0268 0.0339 ...
 $ Area_Small        : num  5.99e+08 5.94e+08 5.89e+08 5.77e+08 5.65e+08 ...
 $ Imp_Cons_Small    : num  4.20e+09 3.76e+09 7.36e+09 7.71e+09 7.63e+09 7.03e+09 6.69e+09 7.37e+09 7.39e+09 5.89e+09 ...
 $ Sup_Rep_Small     : num  6.19e+09 5.37e+09 5.01e+09 5.26e+09 5.43e+09 5.48e+09 5.25e+09 5.29e+09 5.34e+09 5.47e+09 ...
 $ Tractor_Prop_Small: num  3.39e+09 3.36e+09 3.83e+09 4.66e+09 4.15e+09 3.61e+09 3.57e+09 4.32e+09 3.51e+09 4.01e+09 ...
 $ Area_Med          : num  2.02e+08 2.03e+08 2.03e+08 2.07e+08 2.10e+08 ...
 $ Imp_Cons_Med      : num  1.73e+09 2.18e+09 2.39e+09 2.61e+09 2.52e+09 2.70e+09 3.39e+09 4.00e+09 3.33e+09 3.19e+09 ...
 $ Sup_Rep_Med       : num  3.21e+09 3.80e+09 3.18e+09 3.16e+09 3.42e+09 3.72e+09 4.49e+09 4.69e+09 4.78e+09 5.04e+09 ...
 $ Tractor_Prop_Med  : num  2.08e+09 2.08e+09 2.11e+09 2.56e+09 2.72e+09 2.12e+09 2.86e+09 4.26e+09 3.47e+09 4.13e+09 ...
 $ Area_Large        : num  1.41e+08 1.43e+08 1.45e+08 1.48e+08 1.53e+08 ...
 $ Imp_Cons_Large    : num  1.87e+09 2.06e+09 2.05e+09 2.28e+09 2.55e+09 2.97e+09 4.02e+09 4.43e+09 3.38e+09 3.52e+09 ...
 $ Sup_Rep_Large     : num  3.30e+09 3.03e+09 2.81e+09 3.18e+09 3.75e+09 4.20e+09 5.36e+09 5.92e+09 5.38e+09 5.39e+09 ...
 $ Tractor_Prop_Large: num  7.30e+08 7.60e+08 1.06e+09 1.48e+09 1.63e+09 1.57e+09 2.17e+09 2.82e+09 2.32e+09 2.76e+09 ...

summary(FinalData)
  Total.output       X40hp_US        Inflation           Area_Small        Imp_Cons_Small      Sup_Rep_Small       Tractor_Prop_Small     Area_Med          Imp_Cons_Med        Sup_Rep_Med        Tractor_Prop_Med   
 Min.   :0.8547   Min.   : 78995   Min.   :-0.003555   Min.   :404130000   Min.   :3.760e+09   Min.   :4.880e+09   Min.   :3.360e+09   Min.   :202361025   Min.   :1.730e+09   Min.   :3.160e+09   Min.   :2.080e+09  
 1st Qu.:0.9011   1st Qu.: 92196   1st Qu.: 0.015860   1st Qu.:419020000   1st Qu.:6.030e+09   1st Qu.:5.260e+09   1st Qu.:3.610e+09   1st Qu.:210155008   1st Qu.:2.610e+09   1st Qu.:3.720e+09   1st Qu.:2.560e+09  
 Median :0.9455   Median :109612   Median : 0.021301   Median :468200000   Median :6.680e+09   Median :5.360e+09   Median :4.320e+09   Median :255546002   Median :3.200e+09   Median :4.620e+09   Median :4.130e+09  
 Mean   :0.9428   Mean   :108941   Mean   : 0.021046   Mean   :487091176   Mean   :6.464e+09   Mean   :5.356e+09   Mean   :6.364e+09   Mean   :244919749   Mean   :3.099e+09   Mean   :4.334e+09   Mean   :5.119e+09  
 3rd Qu.:0.9939   3rd Qu.:125333   3rd Qu.: 0.028527   3rd Qu.:565186000   3rd Qu.:7.360e+09   3rd Qu.:5.430e+09   3rd Qu.:9.880e+09   3rd Qu.:271560000   3rd Qu.:3.450e+09   3rd Qu.:4.860e+09   3rd Qu.:7.000e+09  
 Max.   :1.0300   Max.   :143574   Max.   : 0.038391   Max.   :599050000   Max.   :7.710e+09   Max.   :6.190e+09   Max.   :1.166e+10   Max.   :275819462   Max.   :4.040e+09   Max.   :5.360e+09   Max.   :1.038e+10  
   Area_Large        Imp_Cons_Large      Sup_Rep_Large       Tractor_Prop_Large 
 Min.   :140658975   Min.   :1.870e+09   Min.   :2.810e+09   Min.   :7.300e+08  
 1st Qu.:152598992   1st Qu.:2.550e+09   1st Qu.:3.750e+09   1st Qu.:1.570e+09  
 Median :193843998   Median :4.020e+09   Median :5.390e+09   Median :2.760e+09  
 Mean   :187807898   Mean   :4.185e+09   Mean   :5.798e+09   Mean   :5.052e+09  
 3rd Qu.:217820000   3rd Qu.:5.780e+09   3rd Qu.:7.910e+09   3rd Qu.:7.320e+09  
 Max.   :227680000   Max.   :7.550e+09   Max.   :9.780e+09   Max.   :1.342e+10 

> sum(is.na(FinalData))
[1] 0
```

I also tried to make a simple lm model but I got the same error.

```
> lm(Val.Pred~., data = FinalData)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Val.Pred ~ ., data = FinalData,  : 
  les longueurs des variables diffèrent (trouvé pour 'Total.output')
```

I would therefore like to know why this error usually occurs and how to correct it.

Thank You

**EDIT**

I forgot to specify that `Val.Pred` is a variable who represents the variable I want to predict. In my case, `Val.Pred` represents X40hp_US.

```
Val.Pred = dlg_list(colnames(ChoixData), multiple = FALSE)$res
PrevData = dlg_list(colnames(ChoixData), multiple = TRUE)$res
```

`dlg_list` from the package svDialogs create a list where I can select the variable I want. The dataframe `ChoixData` contains different columns and then I choose from those which one I want in `FinalData`.

```
Val.Pred = as.name(dlg_list(colnames(ChoixData), multiple = FALSE)$res)
PrevData = as.name(dlg_list(colnames(ChoixData), multiple = TRUE)$res)
```

After adding `as.name` it seems to solve the problem but now I get:

```
> Best_Subset = regsubsets(Val.Pred~. - Total.output, data = FinalData, nbest = 1, nvmax = NULL, force.in = NULL, force.out = NULL, method = "exhaustive")
Error in model.frame.default(data = FinalData, formula = Val.Pred ~ . -  : 
  l'objet n'est pas une matrice
```

Does my data needs to be a matrix to work with the regsubsets function?

**EDIT**

After testing a bit, I found that after removing `as.name` from `PrevData`, the `regsubsets` function worked. I do not know though what difference it makes except that `as.name` remove the `" "` of the answer.

Comment: It's easy to say why this dataset and code yields an error. The LHS of the formula is a name that doesn't equal any to the column names in `FinalData`. However I get an error that says exactlky that, but apparently you have a vector named `Val.Pred` and apparently it's length is not 17. You say you want to find the "best predictors" but you do not say what you're attempting to predict. Voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: Typos? `multpiple` versus `multiple`.

Comment: @r2evans I changed it but it won't affect the rest, `multiple` will only affect the number of choices I can select in the list.